# Booking App, rails views vs webpacker with react or vue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, vue.js, webpacker

I am building web application for doctors and patients to book an appointment online with more other feathers, We are just finished with database structure and coding html/css,

we are wondering which way is good to start with as we are small group of developers, we are aiming to launch our product for both web and ios and android, so we are stuck which way we go; using rails mvc serving views the rails way and building an api for our mobile apps, or going with api only app using webpacker and react or vue js for serving our front-end?

We are planning to add more features for clinics in the future?

Any ideas and suggestions will be very helpful for us.

and thank you in advance

Comment: Your question is rather unclear? What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: Sorry David, I know it's not the right place to answer this kind of questions but i want an advise from a technical guy.

My question is as a team of 3, working on a project that will have a web app and mobile apps, is it good to stick with rails mvc and build a separate api for the mobile apps or go api only app with webpacker and using a frontend framewrok such as reactjs for serving the front-end?
Which way will benefit as on the long run?

Answer (score 1):

This question is better off answered in a more open ended question format type of site like Quora. But heck, I'll give it a shot because I've been here before.

The smaller your team, the more hats each person is going to need to wear. Your risk for "an employee getting hit by a bus" effect is much much higher. If you have a single person dedicated to all things mobile, and they leave for whatever reason - you're going to be scrambling not just to add more features but just to support the existing app.

You need to focus on technology choices that allow you your team to cover as much "area" as possible with the fewest unique tech skills.

Sure this will limit the fanciness of your application. But it will focus your application's purpose and also maximize the output of your team.

My advice is for a team ~ 1 - 5 to stick with Rails and Turbolinks. Go as far as you can making the website mobile like.

When you have a larger team and you can start to dedicate a team to mobile development, I would still consider using React Native or some hybrid web app platform to support as many clients as possible with less unique tech skills.

Comment: Thank you Dylan for the answer, I know it's not the right place to ask this kind of questions. And that was very helpful I have seen rails conf about using turbolinks with native apps and I think it's the best and easy way to go for a small team of 3.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a small team, and you need cross platform functionality, I'd advise you to use **Vue** with **Quasar** framework.

Reasons:

- Its fast and scalable, its built for small teams who require flexibility.
- Has awesome documentation.
- Quasar allows you to build one application and deploy it in all platforms **(Android, Ios and Web)** with just one command.

You will only have to build one app and it will **work on all platforms**.

I hope this was helpful.